# Error: Command '['/path/to/env/bin/python3.7', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, python3, virtualenv

I just installed python3.7 on my 18.04LTS via the deadsnakes ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt install python3.7 -y
```

Now I want to create a virtual environment with `python3.7 -m venv env` but I get

```
Error: Command '['/path/to/desired/env/bin/python3.7', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

`python3 -m venv env0` worked fine before.

Why does this happen?
What can I do to create a virtual environment for python3.7 on Ubuntu 18.04LTS?

Answer (score 104):

I am using python3.9. The command below solved the issue for me:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.9-venv
```

Comment: Logical suggestion, however running the command resulted in `E: Unable to locate package python3.9-venv
`

Comment: @MatejaPetrovic Install deadsnakes ppa first: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`

Comment: @JoelGMathew `Package 'python3.7-venv' has no installation candidate`. Even with deadsnakes.

Comment: @Gulzar It's definitely there. Make sure you ran `sudo apt-get update` first to refresh your local package listing.

Comment: @Cerin I later found out the problem was old ubuntu. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70866415/913098)

Comment: i m on 3.11.6 and was facing the same issue. and it helped right away. thanks for posting it

Answer (score 6):

I realised that python3.7 comes with bionic and removed ppa:deadsnakes/ppa as well as python3.7. After installing it regularly, I got the following:

```
$ python3.7 -m venv v2
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/home/.../v2/bin/python3.7', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

`python3-venv` was already installed, but `python3.7-venv` wasn't, and with that I could create the environment.

Comment: You can create the virtual environment without installing `pip` by default with `python3.7 -m venv --without-pip v2`.

Answer (score 4):

On my machine I've noticed that while `python -m venv` does not work, this command does:

```
virtualenv --python=$(which python3.7) venv
```

**Edit**:

There is a more modern version of this command these days. It should work on python3.7 and up.

```
python3.7 -m venv venv
```

As mentioned in the commands, this command should also work:

```
python3.7 -m virtualenv venv
```

Comment: What is your machine running?

Comment: Works for me on Amazon Linux AMI / RHEL Fedora!

Comment: But `virtualenv` is not the same as `venv`.

Comment: BTW: I think that `python3.7 -m virtualenv venv` does the same as your command (but is easier, IMHO).

Comment: I really do not understand why but `python3 -m venv venv` does not work and `python3 -m virtualenv venv` works on my case. I'm using Python 3.9.7 in Pure OS 10 (Linux based OS )

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me (Thx Joseph..):
sudo apt-get install python3.10-dev
sudo apt-get install python3.10-venv
After this:
python3.10 -m venv venv
works fine!

Answer (score 2):

Use this `apt-get install python3.7-dev python3.7-venv` to install python3.7-dev and python3.7-venv packages and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred to me in a very different scenario. Hope it ends up helping someone.

I was working on my `ntfs` drives and they were being auto-mounted at boot in `/etc/fstab` using `ntfs-3g` with `root` permissions by default.

When trying to create virtualenv it showed me the same error. This was fixed by adding `uid` and `gid` particular flags in `/etc/fstab`

```
UUID=<uuid> <mount-path> ntfs <other-flags>,uid=<uid of user>,gid=<gid of user> 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's useful. Under WSL I had to:

```
$ sudo python3.8 -m venv venv
```

Comment: Solved it for me.   Shame about the downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I had python 2.7 on my system, and the default pip command was pointing to that installation.  I think that's why `python3 -m venv DIR` failed.  This, however, worked:

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
python3 -m virtualenv --python=python3 DIR
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).